# How can I change the Eclipse GUI font?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, ide

How can I change the Eclipse GUI font size?

For instance, I would like to make the font for "Project Explorer" or "Members" smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the controls in Eclipse (such as tree views) use native OS widgets. For these, the font face or size cannot be adjusted in Eclipse. You have to adjust it at OS level.

Comment: i assume this is a regedit that needs to be done. do you know what i would have to change?

Comment: It's in the control panel.

Comment: You're giving insufficiently vague answers. I think what you're saying is to adjust the dpi. However, this solution begs another question. Windows only allows you to set DPI to 100% lowest. You have to adjust via registry to set it to <100%. Since this is a system font I suppose this is the "best" solution.

Comment: I wan't referring to DPI. Depending on the OS and version, you can typically adjust font type and size used for different system widgets.  On Windows 7, for instance, you do this in the control panel under theme options. Microsoft does manage to hide it though. Select your theme, then click on Window Color at the bottom. Then Adjust appearance settings. Then you will be in the right dialog to adjust colors and fonts.

Comment: Apparently, some things can be changed through CSS - see [an answer to *How to change the font size of the Eclipse editor tab's title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317674/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-eclipse-editor-tabs-title/17317754#17317754)*.

Answer (score 9):

Reiterating @Vitor De Mario answer with few more screenshots.

I use Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0) on MacOS Catalina. The font size of Eclipse package explorer was very small and hard to read.
[image]

You can change it through eclipse preferences (shortcut: Command key + ,)
[image]

It looks a lot better now.

[image]

Comment: Nice, but it's not included in the windows version.

Comment: While the option is present in Linux version it doesn't change Package Explorer tree/items font. Some other font related options work though.

Comment: Even when it is present in Windows, and you happen to change it, it is NOT taking effect, at all.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you can change the font for one specific section. However, you can do it for Eclipse as a whole, in *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *View and Editor Folders*, on *Part title font* and *View message font*.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what that changes exactly, however I don't see an adjustment in the size of the font in the views I listed. I had attempted those two settings prior to posting. :(

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work. I tried it on the Preferences screen, but it doesn't seem to have any effect outside it. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Project/Package explorer, Outline window are using OS default font for labels.
For Win 7+ go to *Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization* click *'Window Color'* to start ***'Window Color and Appearance'*** dialog.
Decrease ***'Message Box'*** font.

[image]

Eclipse restart required
In newer versions of Eclipse this becomes configurable (Tree and Table font for views)