# How to change the font size of the Eclipse editor tab's title

Tags: eclipse

It is underlined by a green line. I want to change the font size of the tab's title.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Oops, this tweaking reset some of the syntax highlighting preferences for me... better export your preferences before fiddling this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Eclipse uses CSS for its own styling, so you can modify the CSS file to your needs as explained [here](http://blog.nanthrax.net/2012/07/change-tab-font-in-eclipse-juno/).

The CSS file is located in

```
 ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_X.X.X_V.XXXX/css
```

and the class for the tab titles is named **MPartStack**.

Comment: Newer versions of Eclipse let you configure this under Preferences, as [@Nikolay explains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27299630/25507).

Answer (score 39):

Eclipse Indigo:

Window->Preferences->Appearance->Colors and Fonts

In Colors And Fonts window:

View and Editor Folders->Part title font

Comment: This has torn apart my entire syntax highlighting... I would think twice before touch it :) but then again, maybe it was specific to my setup, with Luna.

Comment: Only works for some tabs (Console, Problems, Advice..) Other tabs don't reflect the change.

Comment: Works for me in Oxygen after the mess caused by changing system language. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Taken from a comment in [Very large tabs in Eclipse panes on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805784/very-large-tabs-in-eclipse-panes-on-ubuntu)

Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Theme -> Classic

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Source ToolSuite 4, it is Window -> Prefernces -> General -> Apparances -> Colors and Fonts and then click on "Part Title Font" open the dialog to adjust the size.