# How do I change the font size of the Eclipse editor tab's title (in Eclipse v4.4 (Luna))?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to achieve the same effect as in Stack Overflow question *[How to change the font size of the Eclipse editor tab's title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317674/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-eclipse-editor-tabs-title)*, but in Eclipse v4.4 (Luna).

Comment: It shoud be the same, edit the CSS

Comment: But unfortunately, it is not! the file structure is different!

Comment: For newer eclipse Mars 4.5 you'll find a dedicated font setting for this: Go to Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> View and Editor Folders -> Part title font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS files in Eclipse 4.4 Luna M6 are now in the `org.eclipse.ui.themes` plugin.

Since Luna is still under development things may still change.

Comment: Confirmed that this is the location after release.